# Understanding reading String using scanner

Tags: java

I want to read an int, double and string and add each one to a variable but I can't read the string.

```
int i = 4;
double d = 4.0;
String s = "My name is ";   
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int i2 = scan.nextInt();
double d2 = scan.nextDouble();
String s2 = scan.nextLine();        
System.out.println(i+i2);
System.out.println(d+d2);
System.out.println(s + s2);
scan.close();
```

my understanding is that `scan.nextLine()` reads a string but it just skips it.
`scan.next()` just reads the first word.
it works properly if i added `scan.nextLine();` before `String str2 = scan.nextLine();` but i dont know why

Comment: readline read all Content until the next EOL

Comment: can you share the input please

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo

Answer (score -1, accepted):

for the input

```
 2.4
 "Some String"
```

When you use nextDouble only 2.4 is picked not the EndOfLine (after 2.4 and before `"Some String"`.).
Hence your code worked by using 2 `nextLine()`.

You could also use

```
int i2 = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
double d2 = Double.parseDouble(scan.nextLine());
String str2 = scan.nextLine();
```

Comment: `The method parseInt(String) in the type Integer is not applicable for the arguments (int)`

Comment: Thanks @joc , edited :)

Comment: @Lokesh Agrawal Got it. Thanks.